# How to index on joined tables

Tags: mysql, index, explain

Total `table_parent` rows: **1318**
Total `table_child` rows: **12 mil++**

```
EXPLAIN
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS table_child.*
  , table_parent.name AS parent_name
from 
  `table_child`
  inner join `table_parent` on `table_parent`.`id` = `table_child `.`parent_id`;
```

Output

```
| id  | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref                     | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | ----------- | ------------ | ---------- | ---- | ------------- | ----- | ------- | ----------------------- | ---- | -------- | ----- |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | table_parent | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL  | NULL    | NULL                    | 1318 | 100.00   | NULL  |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | table_child  | p1,p2,p3   | ref  | idx_1,idx_2   | idx_2 | 5       | db_name.table_parent.id | 447  | 100.00   | NULL  |
```

The `table_parent` filter only in the `join`, can the **rows** further reduce?

Comment: *can the rows further reduce?* Imagine that some parent have no referenced childs... but anycase all 1318 records will be scanned.

Comment: Do you want all that data?  Do you not have a `WHERE` clause to limit _which_ parents or _which_ children to deliver?

Comment: The original query is way complicated than this. Just that the `table_parent` **row** is the same, 1318. Without `WHERE`, the number of **rows** cannot further reduce anymore?